# How to test if the errors of a linear regression are constant?

Tags: r, regression

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Kruskal-Wallis or Fligner test to check homogeneity of variances?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15427/kruskal-wallis-or-fligner-test-to-check-homogeneity-of-variances)

Is there a test to check if the residuls of a linear regression are constant?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean how to check if the residuals of a linear regression have a constant variance? The residuals from a regression will of course per definition be random...

Comment: The residuals can't be constant.  The math of a linear regression is such that some must be positive and some negative.  Perhaps you mean something else.

Comment: To learn about tests for constant variance, you can look up the terms homo- and hetero-skedasticity on this site.  Maybe you had in mind a constant mean.  As in, residuals should not be generally high for some values of predicted Y but generally low for others.  You could test this by dividing your predicted Y into discrete groups and running an anova using the residuals as the dependent variable.

Comment: Closing, because this question is either empty (interpreted as written) or it covers previous ground.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you mean a test for constant variance for the residuals. The following R code illustrates the test.

```
library(lmtest)
# Create data set
y<-sin(1:100)
x<-y+rnorm(100, 0.2, 0.2)
# Build model
lmfit<-lm(y~x)
# Perform the Breusch-Pagan test against heteroskedasticity
res<-bptest(lmfit)
```

If the p-value returned from the bptest is > 0.2 you cannot reject the null hypothesis of constant variance.