# Homogeneity of variance in regression

Tags: regression, assumptions, heteroscedasticity

I have carried out simple linear regression and I am now checking the models meets the assumption of homogeneity of variance:

• am I correct in concluding that the Levenes tests which gave a p<0.05 indicates a violation of homogeneity of variance?

• some models contain 2 or 3 explanatory variables, but in some models, only 1 explanatory variable gave p<0.05 in the Levenes test. Therefore, should only those explanatory variables which gave p<0.05 be corrected?

• is transformation the best place to start when correcting for violation of homogeneity?

Comment: You may be confusing the assumption of "homogeneity of variances" (explanatory variable has distinct groups as in ANOVA) with the assumption of "homoskedasticity" (explanatory variable is continuous as in regression). Levene's test cannot test the latter assumption. See [this answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15427/kruskal-wallis-or-fligner-test-to-check-homogeneity-of-variances/15471#15471) for details.

Comment: Readers may also find this thread of interest: [what-does-having-constant-variance-in-a-linear-regression-model-mean](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52089/).

Answer (score 3):

1. You don't "correct" your covariates; the heterogeneity is in the *residuals*.
2. If you're simply running [Levene's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levene%27s_test) as a factorial ANOVA & finding heterogeneity for *some* of your explanatory variables, you probably have interactions with those variables that you're currently missing & need to add to your model.
3. Transformations *of the response variable* are a good place to start once you've accounted for possible omitted variables (such as interactions).

Comment: re #3: Yes, but "transformations" of *what*? Given that heterogeneity is in the residuals (#1), what could transforming the *explanatory* variables (as suggested in the question) possibly do about that?