# What does having "constant variance" in a linear regression model mean?

Tags: regression, heteroscedasticity

What does having "constant variance" in the error term mean? As I see it, we have a data with one dependent variable and one independent variable. Constant variance is one of the assumptions of linear regression. I am wondering what homoscedasticity means. Since even if I have 500 rows, I would have a single variance value which is obviously constant. With what variable should I compare the variance?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It means that when you plot the individual error against the predicted value, the variance of the error predicted value should be constant. See the red arrows in the picture below, the length of the red lines (a proxy of its variance) are the same.

[image]

Comment: Ok Understood.!! But Since it is an assumption don't we need to validate the assumption before running the model. And why do we need this assumption

Comment: Some assumptions can only be tested after the model is run.  Calculating a model is just math and not the same as interpreting a model.

Comment: Range does not equal variance Penguin Knight so you might want to update your wording here.

Comment: If your variance assumption is wrong, then it will usually mean that the standard errors are wrong and any hypothesis testing could draw the wrong conclusions. (A different John)

Comment: I differ slightly. I wouldn't say that heteroscedasticity necessarily means the standard errors of your betas are wrong, but rather that the OLS estimator is no longer the most efficient unbiased estimator. That is, you could get more power / precision if either you had constant variance (perhaps due to a transformation of Y), or if you accurately took the non-constancy into account (perhaps via the generalized least squares estimator).

Answer (score 70):

This is a place where I've found looking at some formulas helps, even for people with some math anxiety (I'm not suggesting that you do, necessarily).  The simple [linear regression model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression_model) is this:
$$
Y=\beta_0+\beta_1X+\varepsilon  \\
\text{where } \varepsilon\sim\mathcal N(0, \sigma^2_\varepsilon)
$$
What's important to note here is that this model explicitly states once you've estimated the meaningful information in the data (that's the "$\beta_0+\beta_1X$") there is nothing left over but white noise.  Moreover, the errors are distributed as a [Normal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) with a variance of $\sigma^2_\varepsilon$.

It's important to realize that $\sigma^2_\varepsilon$ is not a [variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_%28mathematics%29) (although in junior high school level algebra, we would call it that).  It doesn't vary.  $X$ varies.  $Y$ varies.  The error term, $\varepsilon$, varies *randomly*; that is, it is a [random variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable).  However, the parameters ($\beta_0,~\beta_1,~\sigma^2_\varepsilon)$ are placeholders for values we don't know--they don't vary.  Instead, they are [unknown constants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_%28mathematics%29).  The upshot of this fact for this discussion is that no matter what $X$ is (i.e., what value is plugged in there), $\sigma^2_\varepsilon$ remains the same.  In other words, the variance of the errors / residuals is constant.  For the sake of contrast (and perhaps greater clarity), consider this model:
$$
Y=\beta_0+\beta_1X+\varepsilon  \\
\text{where } \varepsilon\sim\mathcal N(0, f(X))  \\
~  \\
\text{where } f(X)=\exp(\gamma_0+\gamma_1 X)  \\
\text{and }\gamma_1\ne 0
$$
In this case, we plug in a value for $X$ (starting on the third line), pass it through the function $f(X)$ and get the error variance that obtains *at that exact value of* $X$.  Then we move through the rest of the equation as usual.

---

The above discussion should help with *understanding* the nature of the assumption; the question also asks about how to *assess* the it.  There are basically two approaches: formal hypothesis tests and examining plots.  Tests for heteroscedasticity can be used if you have experimental-ish data (i.e., that only occur at fixed values of $X$) or an ANOVA.  I discuss some such tests here: [Why Levene test of equality of variances rather than F-ratio](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/24024/7290/).  However, I tend to think looking at plots is best.  @Penquin_Knight has done a good job of showing what constant variance looks like by plotting the residuals of a model where homoscedasticity obtains against the fitted values.  Heteroscedasticity can also possibly be detected in a plot of the raw data, or in a scale-location (also called spread-level) plot.  R conveniently plots the latter for you with a call to `plot.lm(model, which=2)`; it is the square root of the absolute values of the residuals against the fitted values, with a [lowess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_regression) curve helpfully overlaid.  You want the lowess fit to be flat, not sloped.

Consider the plots below, which compare how homoscedastic vs. heteroscedastic data might look in these three different types of figures.  Note the funnel shape for the upper two heteroscedastic plots, and the upward sloping lowess line in the last one.

[image]

For completeness, here is the code that I used to generate these data:

```r
set.seed(5)

N  = 500
b0 = 3
b1 = 0.4

s2 = 5
g1 = 1.5
g2 = 0.015

x        = runif(N, min=0, max=100)
y_homo   = b0 + b1*x + rnorm(N, mean=0, sd=sqrt(s2            ))
y_hetero = b0 + b1*x + rnorm(N, mean=0, sd=sqrt(exp(g1 + g2*x)))

mod.homo   = lm(y_homo~x)
mod.hetero = lm(y_hetero~x)
```

Comment: thanks it is very helpful . Can you also explain why do we need this assumption in a layman language

Comment: Lemme rephrase my question :
If we apply linear regression on a data which has a BINARY(0,1) dependant variable, the very important assumption of "constant variance" of the dependant variable across independant variables is violated. Can you explain how ?

Comment: You're welcome, @Mukul. The assumption of homoscedasticity (constant variance) is required to make the OLS estimator (ie, the default procedure software uses to estimate betas) the estimation procedure that will produce sampling distributions of betas that have the narrowest standard errors of all the estimation procedures that yield sampling distributions which are centered on the true value. IE, it is necessary for the OLS estimator to be the *minimum variance unbiased estimator*.

Comment: If your response variable is *binary*, it will be distributed as a binomial. IE, *many* parts of the linear regression model described above are inappropriate. 1 of those issues is that, since the variance of a binomial is a function of the mean (mean: $p$, variance: $(p(1-p))/n)$ ), the assumption of homoscedasticity is violated. To understand these things better, it may help to read my answer here: [difference-between-logit-and-probit-models](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20523//30909#30909), although it was written in a different context.

Comment: Appreciate your reply .It is of great help :)

Comment: @gung in your comment you put italics on all the words in the phrase minimum variance unbiased estimator. I understand that with heteroscedasticity the estimator will become less efficient (more variance), but will it become biased too?

Comment: @user1205901, it remains unbiased.

Comment: hi @gung thanks for this informative post.  I know this question is old, but how would one estimate `epsilon=f(X)=gamma_0 + gamma * x`?  In the homoscedastic case, we can estimate `epsilon = SSE / df`.

Comment: That's better asked as a new question, @thc. If that were literally the data generating process for the errors, though, it wouldn't be that hard. You'd get the raw residuals & square them. Then use a GLiM to regress them onto x w/ Gaussian response distribution & a log link.

Comment: @gung - could you share a good resource for the proof of this? Proof that OLS is the *minimum variance unbiased estimator* only if errors have constant variance

Comment: @SachitNagpal, it should be in a decent regression textbook.