# Visually random model residuals, yet heteroskedastic? ( very small Breusch-Pagan Test P-Value)

Tags: r, regression, residuals, heteroscedasticity, scatterplot

Can anyone explain why the BP, Breusch-Pagan, test rejects homoscedasticity with such an apparently randomized plot of residuals?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You  have drawn the wrong scatterplot, I believe.

You  should have a scatterplot of the residuals against the fitted values from the model, not "index" which is just the order in which the observations went into the data set

Comment: I used 
`plot(resid(lm(x)))`

I'm confused because I thought the point of looking at residuals was to ensure that they are evenly scattered about the line Y = 0.

Comment: No. That is true by force. The point is to see if the residuals violate the assumptions of OLS regression: 1) Normally distributed 2) Not related to the fitted values 3) Constant variance at different levels.  Try `plot(m1)` in `R`, where m1 is a linear model; this gives a good default set of graphs

Comment: i replaced the initial plot with he residuals vs fitted plot

Comment: @user1800340, you don't want the residuals vs fitted. This plot tells you there is some curvature in the x y relationship that isn't being captured by your model. To assess homoscedasticity, you want to call `plot(model, which=2)`, which will give you scale-location plot (see my answer [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/52107/7290)).