# How to weight down older data in an OLS fit

Tags: least-squares, weighted-regression, time-varying-covariate, weights

I am doing a ordinary least squares fit. I have data which was recorded at different times. The fit could depend on time so I want to trust my older data less. The obvious way to do this is to weight the data based on how old each data point is and use a weighted least squares fit.

For example, suppose I am trying to fit a linear relationship to estimate the number of people inside McDonald's based on the number of cars in the parking lot. I have [people,cars] data points from many location for the last year recorded a sporadic times. The most recent data should be more useful to predict this relationship as it may change over time but I do not want to throw out older at some arbitrary age.

Is there a standard for this sort of issue or do I need to make some assumption about how the quality of my data ages? Is there a better way to conceptualize this problem?

EDIT:
It is quite possible that there is a trend in the dependant variable as the age changes. In fact the error of each measurement should not change. It might be a better idea to fit that dimension as well and take it out after. In the above example this would be to fit the number of customers inside as a function of cars outside and how long ago the measurement was taken. Then use the current time for predictions.

Comment: Have you looked at Weighted Least Squares? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares#Weighted_least_squares). The answers here might help: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/97832/how-do-you-find-weights-for-weighted-least-squares-regression

Comment: I am using Weighted Least Squares where the weight is 1/age but that function is arbitrary. Looking for a better method.

Comment: Yes, you have to make assumptions.  How else would you figure out the weights?

Comment: I was hoping that there was some sort of standard method. Or at least some way to tell which weight choice would be best. Guess not. i'll stick with 1/age weights