# Can I use residuals for transformation?

Tags: heteroscedasticity, normality-assumption

This may be a simple question, but my data (once transformed) passes normality, however does not pass homoscedasticity. Can I look at the residuals to see if they pass this? or am I over looking this?

Comment: what analytical technique e. g. regression , you want to implement ? what are your residuals representing?

Comment: Which tests do you run to analyze these two things and what is the structure of your data?

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention residuals I assume you are talking about some sort of regression.  In this case, you should be using residuals for all diagnostics.

Specifically, linear regression assumes the **residuals** are i.i.d. Normally distributed, not the dependent variable.

If the residuals severely lack constant variance, then one possible solution is a weighted regression.

P.S.  How do you know your data do not pass homoscedasticity but you have not looked at the residuals?

Comment: I ran a Bartlett's test then ran a model (ANOVA) regardless to look at the residuals. Im working in R at the moment (from my understanding, or package I am using) to run a Barlett's test, you have to insert a model in the script.


I am using "rcompanion" if you are by chance familiar with it

Comment: So ANOVA (which is a type of regression) assumes equal variances.  If the violation is severe (Bartlett's test is one indication it might be a problem, you should visually inspect), then you will want to do a weighted ANOVA to give less importance to the observations with larger variance.

Comment: When you say weighted, are you refering to a Welch's ANOVA?

Comment: no, I'm referring to weighted least squares regression: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/97832/how-do-you-find-weights-for-weighted-least-squares-regression