# Modeling Marketing Sales

Tags: regression, mixed-model, linear-model, stata, marketing

I am working on a problem in which I have daily Sales and daily Offline and Online Marketing Spends. I built a linear regression model where Sales = f(Online Spend, Offline Spend, Lag Sales) at rolled-up weekly level. R square from the model is 92%; however, my intercept is negative, which does not make sense as even intercept should give the unexplained sales which should be non-zero in this case.

[image]

Am I missing something here? What could be possible reasons why the model is throwing a negative intercept? Any alternative suggestion/approach is much appreciated.

Comment: Numerous possibilities, including (1) linear form is a bad idea for your data (2) linear form is OK and your intercept corresponds to values a long way outside the range of your data and is nothing much to worry about. Just staring at numerical output can't give you enough assessment: you should be plotting your data and your results. A scatter plot matrix of your data and added-variable plots after the regression would help.

Comment: On "versus" see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/146533/versus-vs-how-to-properly-use-this-word-in-data-analysis

Comment: Non-zero could mean negative. I think you mean positive.